# Trying to install Playonlinux

Tags: playonlinux

I typed

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

and i get a thing that looks like a Terms of Service at the top it says Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer. At the bottom it has OK but it wont let me click it or press enter. Anyone know how to get pass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.